# When is :$\displaystyle n!=x^n-y^n$ , with , $x,y,n$ are positive integers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm interesting to know if there is general solution for the below equation and it's geometrical interpretation then my question here is :

> > **Question**
> >
> > When is :$\displaystyle n!=x^n-y^n$ , with , $x,y,n$ are positive integers ?

Comment: According to Zsigmondy, practically never as the left hand side has a prime factor greater than n.  Gerhard "Why Ask For This Equation?" Paseman, 2017.02.08.

Comment: May this help ,for large $n$ the equation equivalent to using stiriling equivalence: 

$\frac {x^n}{n!} -\frac {y^n}{n!}\sim \frac{ 1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi. n}}\Big(\frac{ e. x}{ n}\Big)^n-  \frac{ 1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi. n}}\Big(\frac{ e. y}{ n}\Big)^n=1$, but how i can continue ?

Comment: You use that to estimate the size of solutions. You know that any $x$ greater than n/e +1 will be too large, and any $x$ less than n/e will be too small. But it does not matter anyway as there will be a prime factor too big.  Gerhard "Not Good Equation For Study" Paseman, 2017.02.08.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If $n=1$, the answer is yes. Take $x=2, y=1$ so that $1!=2-1$.

If $n>1$, the answer is no. Assume $d=\gcd(x,y)$ and $x=da, y=db, \gcd(a,b)=1$. Suppose 
$$n!=x^n-y^n=d^n(a^n-b^n). \tag1$$

Let $\nu_p(z)$ denote the $p$-adic valuation of $z\in\mathbb{N}$ and $s_p(n)$ be the sum of $p$-ary digits of $n$.

If a prime $p\,\vert\,a$ then $p$ does not divide $a^n-b^n$. Now, if $p\,\vert\,d$ then $\nu_p(d^n)=n\cdot\nu_p(d)>n$. But, Legendre's formula gives $\nu_p(n!)=\frac{n-s_p(n)}{p-1}<n$. That is, $\nu_p(n!)) <\nu_p(d^n(a^n-b^n))$. Absurd. Therefore, $p$ can not divide $d$ and hence $p$ can not divide $n!$ either (since (1) is assumed).

A similar analysis shows: if $p\vert b$ then $p$ does not divide $n$. Well, that means every prime divisor of $a$ is more than $n$. The same is true for $b$ unless $b=1$.

Since $a>b$ are both integers, it follows that $a\geq b+1$ and 
$$d^n(a^n-b^n)>(n+1)^n-n^n>(n+1)^{n-1}.$$
However, it's easy to see that $(n+1)^{n-1}>n!$ and hence a contradiction. So, (1) is impossible!

Comment: More succinctly: For n bigger than 1, one of x and y has to have size bigger than 1. If a prime p divides that bigger number, it can't also divide the smaller number otherwise it divides the factorial too many times. So it can't divide the smaller number and thus can't divide the difference, so p is bigger than n. But this makes the larger number too big.  Gerhard "Likes To Telegraph Proof Sketches" Paseman, 2017.02.08.